# Power BI report

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery, power-bi-report-server

I have a requirement like this. "Report should use the current date and a formula to pull in the prior Sunday date to show the correct Weekly Comment". how to work on this.

Comment: You should have a date table with the days of the week, and using a measure with TODAY() and getting the previous sunday based on that. If you want more answers I would recommend you to had more details regarding your model structure

Comment: Are you looking to limit the data loaded through Power Query, or just the display of data in DAX?